# AWS: How to create a reverse proxy based on URLs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure a Reverse Proxy in my AWS account:

[image]

The Reverse proxy should forward request to internal servers based on their URL structure, e.g.:

```
example.com/question/*   ->  192.168.0.1
example.com/answer/*     ->  192.168.0.2
example.com              ->  192.168.0.3
```

I can implement a Reverse Proxy using Apache's `mod_proxy`, and I wonder if AWS has a built-in solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but in case it helps anyone else: AWS now supports this use case natively using their version 2 ELBs, specifically the Application Load Balancer which was introduced in 2016.

I confirmed with their support that it provides equivalent functionality to running a `mod_proxy`-based Apache reverse proxy.

More details at:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, AWS does not have a built-in implementation for reverse proxy, even for ELBs. You can use Apache, Nginx or HAProxy for a reverse proxy implementation, though.